# Admob testing issue

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, logcat

I have a problem with my admob implementation and is hoping you guys might be able to help me out.

I can't seem to be able to locate the problem in the log and I am pretty lost. My question is - what have I done wrong since the ad won't load. The app is loading fine but the ad doesn't show - why?. Here is my logcat:

```
10-31 22:05:31.191: D/AbsListView(11349): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-31 22:05:31.382: D/dalvikvm(11349): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-16831983.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
10-31 22:05:31.432: I/Ads(11349): Starting ad request.
10-31 22:05:31.552: D/libEGL(11349): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
10-31 22:05:31.552: D/libEGL(11349): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
10-31 22:05:31.562: D/libEGL(11349): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AYELDER_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_JB_2.5.5_CL3556704_release_ENGG (CL3556704)
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): Build Date: 05/17/13 Fri
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): Local Branch: 
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5.5
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): Local Patches: 34c9e193f12610d3e68dabd6198d2c4bfbc66974 RB: Update the master timestamp of the hw_image in rb_texture_update_aliased
10-31 22:05:31.562: I/Adreno200-EGL(11349): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023 + 01d3c78 + e6f0547 +  LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
10-31 22:05:31.602: D/OpenGLRenderer(11349): Enabling debug mode 0
10-31 22:05:31.742: D/dalvikvm(11349): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-16831983.jar' (success) ---
10-31 22:05:31.742: D/dalvikvm(11349): DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.going_android/cache/ads-16831983.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 362ms
10-31 22:05:32.313: W/Ads(11349): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
10-31 22:05:32.323: I/dalvikvm(11349): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.evaluateJavascript
10-31 22:05:32.323: W/dalvikvm(11349): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3227: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
10-31 22:05:32.323: D/dalvikvm(11349): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0016
10-31 22:05:32.363: I/webclipboard(11349): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@418e1fb0
10-31 22:05:32.393: W/Ads(11349): Failed to load ad: 1
10-31 22:05:32.403: D/WebView(11349): onSizeChanged - w:480 h:75
10-31 22:05:32.443: V/webkit(11349): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {418da9a8}
```

Here is the relevant code from the xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY UNIT ID HERE (hidden)"/>
```

And the relevant code from my .java file:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("MY DEVICE ID HERE (hidden)").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I hope you guys can help me out here!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. But I wonder what version of Android (or device) you deployed to to get the log above.

```
10-31 22:05:32.313: W/Ads(11349): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
10-31 22:05:32.323: I/dalvikvm(11349): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.evaluateJavascript
10-31 22:05:32.323: W/dalvikvm(11349): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3227: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
```

These log lines seem to indicate that Admob was looking for a WebKit method that doesn't exist in your Android environment.

The Google Play versions of Admob (which you seem to be using) only support Gingerbread and up.